# Prove that orthocenter of the triangle formed by the arc midpoints of triangle ABC is the incenter of ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle inscribed in circle $W$. Let $X$ be the midpoint of the arc $BC$ not containing $A$ and define $Y$, $Z$ similarly. Show that the orthocenter of $XYZ$ is the incenter $I$ of $ABC$..

This is Lemma 1.42 from Euclidean Geometry In Mathematical Olympiads, and I'm stuck.

I tried defining a phantom point $D$, where $D$ is the intersection of $AX$ and $ZY$ and then proving that angle $ADZ = 90$ degrees, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: You have the right idea about what needs to be proven. To get there, consider, for instance, what $\angle BAZ$, $\angle XAB$, and $\angle AZY$ tell you about $\triangle ADZ$.

Comment: look for cyclic quadrilaterals. and you will get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}$
The simplest way to prove $AX\perp YZ$ is using the angle between intersecting secants theorem which states:

> If two lines intersect inside a circle, then the measure of the angle
> formed is one half the sum of the measure of the arcs intercepted by
> the angle and its vertical angle.

Thus
$$\begin {align}
\angle ADZ&=\frac12\big (\arc{AZ}+\arc{XY}\big)=\frac12\big (\arc{AZ}+\arc{XC}+\arc{CY}\big)\\
&=\frac14\big (\arc{AB}+\arc{BC}+\arc{CA}\big)=\frac\pi2.
\end {align}$$

Comment: can you please explain what happens when we show angle $ADZ = 90$ degrees? How is this related to incenter of triangle $ABC$?

Comment: @SayemRahman $AX$ is angle bisector of  $\angle BAC $. If $AX\perp YZ $ the line is also the altitude of $\triangle XYZ$. By symmetry the same is true for $BY,CZ$ as well.